# Optimal database structure/query for one vote per ip address per image per month

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I'm looking to create  website where unregistered users can rate multiple images from 1-10, but only once per IP per month for each image.

I was thinking about database structure like this:

Pictures

- id
- url
- uploadDate
- avgRating

Votes

- idVote
- idPic
- vote
- ipAddress
- date

and then getiing data with query like

```
SELECT * from Pictures 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT idPic 
    from Votes 
    WHERE ipAddress='$ip' 
        AND date BETWEEN $firstdayofthemonth AND $lastdayofthemonth 
  ) 
SORT BY avgRating
```

(Don't worry about syntax errors, I haven't use SQL for awhile now and I'll figure it out myself)

Anyway, I think this isn't the optimal way and that this query may be slow, and I would use it to display every individual picture every time (very frequent use).

Are there any better approaches for my problem?

Comment: Change SORT for ORDER...

Comment: As long as you have an index with IP as the first field and date as the next, the sub-select should work fast enough.

Comment: Yeah, I decided that I'll just use my original idea, since I run some tests and query execution time was pretty acceptable actually. Thanks for you comments.